# Interpreting a TestFlight crash report

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, crash

I just made some updates to my app, and have been seeing some new crash reports in TestFlight that I can't find much information on online. Can anyone help me interpret what's going on here? It's happening in different places throughout my app, so I don't think it's related to one specific function...

```
0 MyApp 0x000832b6 testflight_backtrace + 238
1 MyApp 0x00083fa0 TFSignalHandler + 264
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x35e2be92 _sigtramp + 42
3 libdispatch.dylib 0x3a3c611e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
4 libdispatch.dylib 0x3a3c611e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x3a3c54b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x3a3ca1bc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 224
7 CoreFoundation 0x38739f3a __CFRunLoopRun + 1290
8 CoreFoundation 0x386acebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
9 CoreFoundation 0x386acd48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
10 GraphicsServices 0x36c5d2ea GSEventRunModal + 74
11 UIKit 0x39e7a2f8 UIApplicationMain + 1120
12 MyApp 0x0003078a main (main.m:16)
13 MyApp 0x0003073f start + 39
```

Comment: Looks like you need to symbolicate the crash report to translate those 0x strings into methods from your app. I’m not sure how to do that, but if you look for TestFlight Symbolicate you should be able to find out how.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my crash logs in TestFlight are getting symbolicated, since other TF crash reports are showing up with full method names. Can some crash reports get unsymbolicated somehow?